# Best way to select from two MySQL tables with multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, select, join, subquery

Given two MySQL tables:

```
member: id, status, name, type
serial: id, serial, description
```

I want to select the IDs where member.status = "2" and serial = any serial where ID is a specified value.

So in other words, given an ID, I want to find the distinct serial numbers associated with an ID, then return ALL IDs that have that serial number - but only if their status is "2".

I don't think that I want a JOIN or a UNION.  I probably want to select serial.id where serial=ANY(select serial where serial.id="value") - but I can't figure out how to require member.status = "2".

How should I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help convey what you are trying to do.  For instance, `id` of what?  Member or serial?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should work. Use a subquery to find all `serial` numbers associated with a specified `id`, then find all `id`s whose `serial` is in the result of the subquery; put an inner join in the outer query to match `status` to `id`.

```
SELECT m.id
  FROM member m
  JOIN serial s
    ON s.id = m.id
  WHERE s.serial IN
    (SELECT serial
      FROM serial
      WHERE id = :search_id) ids
    AND m.status = '2';
```

Comment: Unfortunately it finds 0 records where there should be at least two.

Comment: What do you get from just the subquery?

Comment: I found the problem.  There was a failure case where the serial number was null in some cases, causing bogus matches.  It works fine now; thank you!!